# rbind dataframe rows with common IDs

Tags: r

```
df1 <- read.table(
  text = "ID   A    B    C
    1    0    0    0
    1    1    0    1
    3    1    1    1", header = T
)

df2 <- read.table(
  text = "ID   A    B    C
    1    49   49   32
    8    2    9    3
    9    4    2    0", header = T
)
```

Result

```
ID   A    B    C
1    0    0    0
1    1    0    1
1    49   49   32
```

I need to make a dataframe composed of all columns of original dataframes (they are already made up of same columns) where both of the original dataframes have some ID's that are common. In the example, df1 and df2 both have rows with ID's of 1, so the result dataframe has all rows from both dataframes that have ID's of 1 in it.

Comment: what `r` code have you tried? (edit it into your question)

Comment: Hey Nate, haven't exactly tried much because I don't know how to do it--I don't believe merge will work for me, but its the only thing I've thought of

Comment: Do you mean you want to select the rows with a given ID and then bind them together?

Comment: OP says its based on the intersection of `ID` columns

Comment: Oh missed that.

Comment: @rdk use that `read.table()` format for posting data next time, save others from scrounging to input you data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first get common `ID`s using `intersect` and then subset and `rbind` both dataframes -

```
valid_ids <- intersect(df1$ID, df2$ID)

rbind(df1[df1$ID %in% valid_ids, ], df2[df2$ID %in% valid_ids, ])

  ID  A  B  C
1  1  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  1
3  1 49 49 32
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
list(df1, df2) %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = 'grp') %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(grp) > 1) %>% 
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   ID [1]
#     ID     A     B     C
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     0     0     0
#2     1     1     0     1
#3     1    49    49    32
```